# How Progress bar move on div scroll not on window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar, scrollbar

Here, My progress bar and that progress bar move when I scroll window.

But I want when I scroll window it detects div not window. I write code for window and it perfectly worked for on window scroll.

Here, is my code for perfectly work for window scroll.
How it moves on div.
[image]

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
            documentHeight = $(document).height(),
            windowHeight = $(window).height();
            scrollPercent = (scroll / (documentHeight-windowHeight)) * 100;
            var position = scrollPercent;

    $("#progressbar").attr('value', position);

    });
```

```css
progress {
        height: 6px;
        width: 100%;
        position:fixed;
        margin-left: -48px;
        margin-top: -20px;
    }
```

```html
<div type="slideshow" id ="slide">
<section>
  <header>date </header>
  <section>content</section>
</section>
<section>
  <header>date </header>
  <section>content</section>
</section>
<section>
  <header>date </header>
  <section>content</section>
</section>
<section>
  <header>date </header>
  <section>content</section>
</section>
</div>
```

What should i do to resolve this error.
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which div you want to detect on scroll?

Comment: whose id slide.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your example?

Comment: you not getting my point dude... inside my div i have scrollbar and progress bar they should when i scroll cursor inside div then progress bar move

Answer (score 0):

here is an example for your question

html:

```
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
```

css:

```
.parent{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
}
.child{
  background: rebeccapurple;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

the point is set the parent div `overflow: auto;`

Comment: you not getting my point dude... inside my div i have scrollbar and progress bar they should when i scroll cursor inside div then progress bar move

Comment: you should changed the width of the progress bar when you scroll